# Wait for child component's update on binding to propagate to the parent in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Am new to AngularJS. Am trying to build a component for paging that updates the current page. The problem I am having is that when the component makes a change to a value that has two-way bindings. The new value is not immediately available to the parent.

Is there something I should do in order to wait for the binding value to update? Or is this a patterning issue where I should be taking a different approach to solve the problem?

## Component - paging.js

```
angular.module('someModule')
.component('paging', {
bindings: {
  page:   '=',
  getNextPage: '='  // <- Side note: This is a function, I had problems using the '&' binding
},
controller: function($scope) {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.nextPage = function () {
      $ctrl.page++;
      $ctrl.getNextPage();   // <-- Parent will still have the old value for 'page'

      // THIS WOULD WORK, PARENT WOULD HAVE THE UPDATED VALUE FOR 'page'
      // setTimeout(function(){
      //   $ctrl.action();  
      // }, 1000);

      // COULD ALSO PASS THE VALUE THIS WAY
      // $ctrl.action($ctrl.page); 
    }

});
```

## Parent controller

```
...
  $scope.getNextPage = function () {
      $scope.page; // <- This still has the old value 
      ...
  }

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly, check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/gz4g5Lp1/10/) where you can see FOUR different options of binding to for your page index.**

Inspecting your posted code, I don't see anything wrong, probably your problem is in the *HTML template*.

**OPTION 1:** Bind `page` variable and increase it inside the component

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <paging page="page"></paging>
</div>
```

*CONTROLLER:*

```
function parentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.page = 1;
}
```

*COMPONENT:*

```
var pagingComponent = {
    bindings: {
        page: '='
    },
    template: '<div><button ng-click="$ctrl.nextPage();">Next Page</button></div>',
    controller: function() {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.nextPage = function() {
           $ctrl.page++;
        };
    }
}
```

**OPTION 2:** Bind `getNextPage()` function form parent controller

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <paging get-next-page="getNextPage()"></paging>
</div>
```

*CONTROLLER:*

```
function parentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.page = 1;
    $scope.getNextPage = function(page) {
        $scope.page++;
    }
}
```

*COMPONENT:*

```
var pagingComponent = {
    bindings: {
        getNextPage : '&'
    },
    template: '<div><button ng-click="$ctrl.nextPage();">Next Page</button></div',
    controller: function() {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.nextPage = function() {
           $ctrl.getNextPage();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking over your jsFiddle, it looks like you've came to the same conclusion that I have? - Which is that the only way to set the new page in the child component and then make the new page immediately available in the parent's function is to pass the new page number though as a parameter. In your other examples, it looks like you are actually incrementing the page number in the parent.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion. You have to pass the `$scope.page` variable to the child component... Probably there are other ways to do it, but I think that it is a clear way to do it. Anyway, if some of the options doesn't resolve your problem, tell me and I can update my jsFiddle or my answer. --- Good Luck :)